# Square integrable continuous function and the square summability of a sequence formed from its values on a countable dense subset.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a square integrable continuous function of the form $f:
(0,1) \to\mathbb{R}$. Consider a countable dense subset $D$ of $(0,1)$ and let $k:\mathbb{N} \to D$ be one of its enumerations. Now consider the infinite sequence $\{x_n\}$ where $x_n = f(k(n))$, $n = 1,2,3,...$.

Can we say that $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_i^2}$ exist?

Comment: Intuition : A continuous function is uniquely determined by its values on a countable dense subset.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint :* prove the norm of $E_N = \{k(n), 0\le n\le N\}$ goes to $0$ as $N$ goes to infinity, then use Riemann integrals